# 'cordova.plugins' does not exist in Ionic2

Tags: cordova, ibeacon, ionic2, ibeacon-android

I have just started building an Ionic2 app using TypeScript. I am trying to access a cordova plugin https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon. I have successfully added it to my project, but I when I try to access it using

```
cordova.plugins.locationManager
```

the build engine does not recognise **cordova**.

The instructions for the plugin suggest this is how Version 2 should be accessed but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please post the code which your are using for this plugin invocation It should be invoked inside platform ready function

Comment: Able to post the exact error message when you run your application? Also, are you running it in a browser or on a physical device. To run cordova.js, the application must be run on a physical device and not on a browser.